# React Web Navbar Tree Menu Activation

Tags: css, reactjs, navigation

I am working on a NavBar with drop-down menu. Everything is working fine, but I need to show the Tree menu on click. The problem is how to make visible only the menu that user clicked. I am adding 'active' className to display it.

So, when user click 'Products' tab, it should only display the Products menu, not every menu at once.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>Nav Item1</p>
      <div className='menu active'>
        <ul>
          <li>Menu Item 1</li>
          <li>Menu Item 2</li>
          <li>Menu Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Nav Item2</p>
      <div className='menu'>
        <ul>
          <li>Menu Item 1</li>
          <li>Menu Item 2</li>
          <li>Menu Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Nav Item3</p>
      <div className='menu'>
        <ul>
          <li>Menu Item 1</li>
          <li>Menu Item 2</li>
          <li>Menu Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

So whenever I click on Nav Item, it should render the menu. Is there an easy way to do it? Or I need to create a function and state variable for every Nav Item?

Comment: Can you add some code to show us what you're talking about? It's impossible to know what you mean right now

Comment: I added some code example and clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to answer. But your activation should use the items possible as children and only display them when it is activated.

The easier way then uses classes in React is using booleans directly.
This is possible due to `false` used as `null` and therefore not rendering.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface Props {
  tabName: string;
}

class TabAndMenu extends React.Component<Props> {
  private visible = false;

  render() {
    return 
      <><span onClick={() => this.visible = true}>{this.props.tabName}</span>
       {visible && this.props.children}
      </>
  }  
}
```

If you need more specific help, you should post a jsfiddle/code sandbox or other ways of showing us your code.

Comment: My code is quite bulky and it would be hard to understand. But I will add an example to my post of what it looks.